# how to get bash and zsh setup correctly on macOS mojave

Tags: zsh, bashrc, .bash-profile, oh-my-zsh

I'm running macOS (Mojave.)

I'm wanting to make the switch from default bash to zsh/oh-my-zsh.

Everything I install assumes I'm going to be editing my .bash_profile (or .bashrc.) I'm not 100% on how to interperet this; do I replace .bash_profile with .zshrc?

Honeslty the subject of .bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile, .zshrc is a sourse of stress for me as a junior superuser/sysadmin.

I could use some advice on how to get .bash_profile, .basrc, .profile, .zshrc, etc. setup correctly.

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) has all the info you need regarding the startup files.

Answer (score 0):

For smooth migration from Bash to ZSH. Copy `~/.bashrc` as `~/.zshrc`. You may need to merge the contents if there's one `~/.zshrc` already.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your `.bash_profile` contents to `.zshrc`. They should be compatible.

I'd recommend installing the latest zsh via Brew. Then installing the following via Brew to enhance zsh:

- [powerlevel9k](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k)
- [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions)
- [zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions)
- [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting)

Follow the instructions from the Brew CLI output on how to load these enhancements at login.

Before fully committing to zsh, you can use iTerm2 to configure a profile for Bash and another profile for zsh until you're fully comfortable with the new shell.

If you're coming from Bash, some paths are loaded from `/etc/paths.d/`. So for example if you're using iTerm2 to load zsh by command: `/usr/local/bin/zsh`, for some weird reason `/etc/zprofile` & therefore `/etc/paths.d/` are not loaded. To fix this just change the command to `/usr/local/bin/zsh -l` so that zsh loads as a login shell.

Here's a better explanation [why the default zsh session is not a login session](https://serverfault.com/a/901476/458011).